# Format the list data merge coloumns

Tags: c#, linq

For example, how can I group the following records by GroupId using LINQ, and (thus merging all rows in each group into one)

```
Id| Name    | FatherName|Nmber      |Clone   |Demand | Supp  |Survival 
1 | Farmer1 | FFather1  |9876543210 |G-48    |200    |  200  |150
1 | Farmer1 | FFather1  |9876543210 |L-48/49 |150    |  150  |150
1 | Farmer1 | FFather1  |9876543210 |Uday    |400    |  400  |300
3 | Farmer23| FFather3  |9876543210 |G-48    |1212   |1212   |1210          
3 | Farmer23| FFather3  |9876543210 |L-48/49 |2121   |2121   |2000
```

Please let me know how can i add these with seperated comma not add these values Expected result is :
    **Need OutPut:**

```
Id|Name    | Father  | Number    |G-48=/de/sup/sur|L-48/49=de/sup/sur|Uday=de/sup/sur
1 |Farmer1 | FFather1| 9876543210|200,200,150     |150,150,150       |400,400,300
3 |Farmer23| FFather3| 9876543210|1212/1212/1210  |2121/2121/2000    |null
```

Please help let me know how can i merge this expected result

i had try but not get accurately

```
var data = result.GroupBy(i => i.id).Select(g => new
                {
                    Id= g.Key,
                    FarmerName = g.Select(i => i.FarmerName ).FirstOrDefault(),
                    FatherName = g.Select(i => i.FatherName ).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Number= g.Select(i => i.Number).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Demand = String.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.Demand)),
                    Supply= String.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.Supply)),
                    Survival= String.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.NoOfPlantSurviving)),
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: At a glance that looks right. What was the problem you had with it? eg what output did you get...

Comment: i need to create coloumn name according "clone" and concat last three columns

Comment: Ah, I see so your actually have a variable amount of columns based on how many rows have the same ID? What are you ultimately using this for? Are you passing it to something that could just loop through the grouped rows to get that data rather than making it use a column for each old row which strikes me as a very hard way to do this? I certainly can't think of a way to do it in LINQ. It might also be worth editing your question to highlight this requirement - when I first saw it I didn't notice and assumed you were doing group by and aggregating.